# initially empty list but dynamically adding item to list is giving error in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a empty list and I add item to it dynamically.I tried to access list item but got an error.It gives an error of
**Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' has no instance getter 'id'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:3
Tried calling: id)**

**List likesCount=[];**

I add item to list

```
           for(var j=0;j<snapshot.data!.length;j++){
                
                  likesCount.add({"like":snapshot.data![j].likes!.length,"id":snapshot.data![j].postId,"index":j});
            
          }
```

I tried to access with

```
                           if(likesCount.isNotEmpty){
                              for(var m=0;m<likesCount.length;m++){
                                Text(likesCount[m].id)
                              }
                             }
```

Comment: Please include more declarations and code for `likesCount`. It's hard to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I have already added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `List<Map>` thats why you need to access the data with map too.

The issue is here `Text(likesCount[m].id`. You call the id with assumtion its an `List<Object>`.

Solution:

```
 if(likesCount.isNotEmpty){
    for(var m=0;m<likesCount.length;m++){
      Text(likesCount[m]["id"]) // this is how to get value in map
    }
 }
```